# Fixed points of multivariable calculus

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I have discrete case.

$z=1-x-y$;

$x=a_1(x^{2}+2yz)+a_2(z^{2}+2xy)+a_3(y^{2}+2xz)$;

$y=b_1(x^{2}+2yz)+b_2(z^{2}+2xy)+b_3(y^{2}+2xz)$;

$z=c_1(x^{2}+2yz)+c_2(z^{2}+2xy)+c_3(y^{2}+2xz)$;

where $a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2, b_3, c_1, c_2, c_3, $ are arbitrary which value less than 1.

To find the behavior of fixed point, i can't use jacobian because at point (0,0,0), jacobian gives me input of all 0, which is not useful.

Thus, i try for Hessian at point (0,0,0). What kind of properties of the eigenvalues of Hessian to see the dynamical system?
Because if in jacobian, modulus of eigenvalues less than 1 gives me convergence of fixed point. Then i'm asking for properties of Hessian's eigenvalues to see the dynamical system of my fixed points.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please, use latex to edit your post. Write all the equations like you wrote the first ($y=1-x-y$). Then write what you want to prove. Right now, your motivation is unclear. If you just want to find the fixed point, then $(0,0,0)$ is one. I don't know if any others exist.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had correct them all using latex notation.

Answer (score 0):

If the differential vanishes, then the fixed point is called superattracting and all the points of a certain neighborhood converge under iteration to the fixed point.

Comment: u meant the jacobian?

Comment: the jacobian matrix, if you prefer. it's a matricial representation of the differential

Comment: Could you give me some reference books or articles about this? When the case of entry Jacobian is all zero, then the "fixed point is called superattracting and all the points of a certain neighborhood converge under iteration to the fixed point".